# Access to out-of-scope variable within anonymous functions in Laravel (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, anonymous-function, eloquent

I want to seed the related tables in Laravel. I had a problem in access to the out-of-scope variable inside the anonymous function which I had defined for `whereHas` methods to put "where" conditions on my has queries.

```php
$id = $user->id; // out-of-scope variable
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', $id);
})->get();
```

Technically I don't have access to `$id` inside the anonymous function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't a Laravel question, but a PHP one. Just add `use ($variable)` after the parameter list:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->where('user_id', $id);
})->get();
```